# How come my Component resets to its default values?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

So I'm building a calendar and I've got it to work the only problem is on main shell when changing the year the values of my hooks go back to their default value. the current month and year. I tried `e.preventDefault()` but it doesn't help my hooks from going back to default.

My `MainShell` component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Calender } from "./calender";

export function MainShell(props) {
  let [month, setMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth() + 1);
  let [year, setYear] = useState(new Date().getFullYear());
  let [thisMonth, setthisMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth() + 1);
  let [thisYear, setthisYear] = useState(new Date().getFullYear());

  const setEvent = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setMonth(parseInt(thisMonth));
    setYear(parseInt(thisYear));
    console.log("hi");
  };

  if (month != -1) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Calender year={year} month={month} />
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={setEvent}>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="month">Month:</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                value={thisMonth}
                id="month"
                name="month"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setthisMonth(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="year">Year:</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                id="year"
                name="year"
                value={thisYear}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setthisYear(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```

My `Calender` component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Week } from "./week";

export function Calender(props) {
  let [month, setMonth] = useState(props.month);
  let [year, setYear] = useState(props.year);
  let [currentCalender, setCurrentCalender] = useState([]);

  const daysOfMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  function dayOfWeek(month, year) {
    //solution founded in this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGZ1uPj6m7Q&t=165s

    //take away the centuries
    let yearOfFocus = year % 100;
    let isLeapYear = false;
    if (yearOfFocus % 4 == 0) {
      isLeapYear = true;
    }
    let monthCode = [
      [6, 5],
      [2, 1],
      [2],
      [5],
      [0],
      [3],
      [5],
      [1],
      [4],
      [6],
      [2],
      [4],
    ];
    let specificCode = -1;

    //how to calculate day

    //find the code of the month
    if ((month == 1 || month == 2) && isLeapYear) {
      specificCode = monthCode[month - 1][1];
    } else {
      specificCode = monthCode[month - 1][0];
    }

    // 0 and 7 is sunday so monday 1

    //year code spanning from 1900-2199
    let bonusYearCode = 0;
    if (year / 100 == 19) {
      bonusYearCode = 1;
    } else if (year / 100 == 21) {
      bonusYearCode = 5;
    }

    let yearCode = yearOfFocus + Math.trunc(yearOfFocus * 0.25);

    yearCode = (yearCode % 7) + bonusYearCode;

    return (specificCode + 1 + yearCode) % 7;
  }
  function firstWeek(day, week) {
    let currentWeek = [];
    let lastMonth = month - 2;
    if (lastMonth < 0) {
      lastMonth = daysOfMonth[12];
    } else {
      lastMonth = daysOfMonth[lastMonth];
    }
    let digit = 0;
    for (let i = day - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      week.unshift(lastMonth - digit);
      digit++;
    }
    return week;
  }
  function lastWeek(calender) {
    let nextDay = 1;
    let week = calender[calender.length - 1];
    for (let i = week.length; i < 7; i++) {
      week.push(nextDay);
      nextDay++;
    }

    return week;
  }
  function getCalender(day) {
    let calender = [];
    let week = [];
    if (day != 1 && calender.length < 1) {
      week = firstWeek(day, week);
    }
    let limit = daysOfMonth[month - 1];
    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      if (week.length == 7) {
        calender.push(week);
        week = [];
      }
      week.push(i + 1);
    }
    if (week.length > 0) {
      calender.push(week);
    }
    if (calender[calender.length - 1].length < 7) {
      week = lastWeek(calender);
      calender[calender.length - 1] = week;
    }

    setCurrentCalender(calender);
  }
  function getDay(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    let day = dayOfWeek(month, year);
    getCalender(day);
  }, []);

  return (
    <table id="calender">
      <thead>
        <tr id="calender header">
          <th>Sunday</th>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <th>Wednesday</th>
          <th>Thursday</th>
          <th>Friday</th>
          <th>Saturday</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {currentCalender.map((e, i) => {
          return <Week list={e} key={"week" + i} getDay={getDay} />;
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please remove the term "main shell" from your post, no one knows what that means except for you, and it makes the title and post confusing.

Comment: Tangential, but consider using the spacebar more and indenting consistently--it makes code much easier to read and think about.